# blueimp fileupload with angularjs not uploading anything

Tags: angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I'm writing some tests trying to get the blueimp jquery-fileupload plugin working with angularjs.

Here is what I wrote, trying to keep it as simple as I could :

[controller.js]

```
app.controller('myAppController', function ($scope, uploadHandlerUrl) {
    $scope.options = {
        url: uploadHandlerUrl,
        add: function(e,data) {
            angular.element('#submit').click(function() {
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            console.log('done', data);
        },
        progress: function(e,data) {
            console.log('progressing', data)
        }
    };
});;
```

[html]

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-fileupload="options">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can also see a running instance [here](http://dev.uselessworks.com/fileupload-angular/).

The problem is, every data object that is returned by the fileupload plugin seems to tell me that eveything went fine, but no files are actually uploaded on the server (the files should be uploaded [here](http://dev.uselessworks.com/fileupload-angular/server/php/files/)).

It may be caused by some configuration issue on my server, but I've absolutely no idea in which direction I should search.
I'm using blueimp native uploadHandler.php on the server-side

Answer (score 2):

This might save you hassle if you are looking for file upload using AngularJS

https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

It is basically a directive like tosh's answer that takes care of non-HTML5 browsers with FileAPI flash polyfill and has $http.uploadFile function to upload the actual file via AJAX.

This issue [Everything looks to be working, but no file in upload folder](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/6) seems very similar to yours you can ask him how he fixed it.

Comment: this looks strongly like a solution to my problem, thank you very much, I'll give it a try when I find some time.

Comment: Is it cross-browser solution ?

Comment: Yes it is. It uses Flash and FileAPI for non-html5 browsers.